# Difference between FindInstance and NSolve

Tags: equation-solving

Assume that

```
w[n_] :=Expand[Sum[Binomial[n - k - 1, k]*(-1)^k*A^(n - 2*k - 1), {k, 0, n - 1}]]
f[y_, z_]:=PolynomialRemainder[(w[z] - 1)*(w[y] - 1), (w[i] - 1), A]
h[{y_, z_}] :=Quiet[N[FindRoot[Abs[f[y, z]] - w[i] + 1 == 0, {A, 10000000}]]]
For[i = 153, i < 210, i++,Print[{i}, Max[ParallelMap[h, Subsets[Range[i + 1, 210], {2}]]]]]
```

According to above code, there are lots of roots.

But, when I try to find them with `NSolve`, there is no root. Why?

Comment: Actually it gives and a lot of them! One question why you have chosen 10000000 as the initial value? For that initial value it seems that the method is diverging ...

Comment: @Spawn1701D,Because i want to find the greatest root for all cases. and i guess only where the root? Why does it give? When i try to solve with `NSolve`, i could not have any solutions.

Comment: Try just one step, take i = 153 construct the subset `Subsets[Range[i + 1, 210], {2}]`and take the first pair. if you run h you will get `{A -> 5.16816*10^6}` substitute this value on `Abs[f[y, z]] - w[i] + 1 == 0` and you will get a huge number, in other word for that initial value the method diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for h:

```
h[{y_, z_}] :=Quiet[NSolve[Abs[f[y, z]] - w[i] + 1 == 0, A,Reals]]
```

Also `Max` won't work try instead this

```
For[i = 153, i < 210, i++,
    Print[{i}, ParallelMap[Sort[h[#]][[-1]]&, Subsets[Range[i + 1, 210], {2}]]]]]
```

or alternatively,

```
For[i = 153, i < 210, i++,
    Print[{i}, ParallelMap[{A->Max[h[#][[All,All,2]]]}&, Subsets[Range[i + 1, 210], {2}]]]]]
```

(using `Sort` is faster)